# Zend Routing: Route to route ID

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

Is it possible to use the Routes ID to redirect to within the controller?

For example, I predefine the login and logout URL with the id of login and logout. In my controller I determine the user needs to be logged out, can I redirect them to that route using the routes id?

**Bootstrap**

```
$router->addRoute('logout',new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('logout', array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'logout')));
$router->addRoute('login', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('login', array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'login')));
```

**Controller**

```
return $this->_redirect('login');
```

Currently the above wouldn't work, Id have to use /login (aka the base URL to the route).

Comment: Why you use return, without return "$this->_redirect('login')" affairs?

Comment: +1 for sensible comment! :LOL:

Comment: @azz0r when you say route-id, What is route-id?

Comment: Btw.. +1 for a good question! Am researching......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement recently too, the way I solved it was to use the router to assemble the url, and then perform the redirect.

```
$redirectUrl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->assemble($userParams, $routeName);
$this->_redirect($redirectUrl);
```

See [Zend_Controller_Router_Interface](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/db_Zend_Controller_Router_Interface.html#%5CZend_Controller_Router_Interface)::assemble

Answer (score 0):

From Zend Framework 1.8

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                                           'index/:ident',
                                            array(
                                                     'module' => 'user'
                                                     'controller' => 'index',
                                                     'action' => 'login'
                                                  ),
                                             array(
                                            // match only digits
                                                    'ident' => '\d+'
                                                   )
                                            );
```

Comment: I know how to to define a route (see my first part). Im not sure you understand my question